# How to get compiler warnings for all units of compilation in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, compiler-warnings

While cleaning the code and eliminating compiler warnings in Qt Creator I found that the IDE shows warnings in the "Issues" tab for just a single compilation unit only. That is not very convenient if I have multiple units and if I need to see all warnings for the project (even for multiple libraries joined by a single .pro file). What is the best way to see all warnings or at least to see whether any warning is produced for the whole project?

**Update:** Looks like this problem is specific to the version of Qt Creator. As I can see, the version 4.11.0 splits the warnings by compilation units while much older version 3.5.1 doesn't.

Comment: Tell Qt creator to Rebuild All. It will rebuild all code.

Comment: @NickM. that rebuilds the code, but I still have to iterate over all .cpp files selecting them and openning in the editor. That allows to see the warnings that the compiler has generated per source file. I wish to see the list for the whole project without the need to open each file.

Comment: If you do a rebuild all if should then put all the warnings and errors in the issues window. Make sure you don't have the warnings hidden in the issues window. If that doesn't work you can also delete the build folder and force Qt to completely rebuild everything even the Qt cache build files

Comment: @NickM. Looks like this problem is specific to the version of Qt Creator. The version 4.11.0 splits warnings by compilation unit, while 3.5.1 doesn't.